# Proof that $\int_0^\infty\ln^{s-1}(t+1)dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{s-1}(t+1)}{t}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I proved that$$\int_0^\infty\ln^{s-1}(t+1)dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{s-1}(t+1)}{t}dt.$$ When $s$ is a zero of the zeta function $\zeta(s)$. Is my proof correct?:$$0=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}dt\\ =\int_0^\infty\frac{(t-1)\ln^{s-1}(t+1)}{t}dt \text{ (by substitution of $u=e^t-1$ then change variables)}\\ =\int_0^\infty \ln^{s-1}(t+1)dt-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{s-1}(t+1)}{t}dt\\ \implies\int_0^\infty\ln^{s-1}(t+1)dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{s-1}(t+1)}{t}dt$$I am not sure if I was allowed to separate the integrals, so I am feeling skeptical.

Comment: I’m skeptical about that integral representation for $\zeta$. We all know it’s valid for real $s>1$, but what the domain of validity is in the complex plane (with what choice of definition for $x^s$) I don’t know. It may be the case that, for this special zero $s$, the integral does not converge. E.g. think about the trivial zeroes. The domain of $s$ must be carefully considered. I’m also very tired, so forgive me if I’m wrong on this last point, but I don’t think you did your first integral substitution correctly!

Comment: The domain of validity of the integral representation for $\zeta(s)$ is $\Re (s)>1$. There are no zeros of $\zeta$ in that domain. Also the result after making the change of variables is incorrect. It should be $du/(u+1)$ and not $(u-1)du$ ($u=t$ in your case).

Comment: @Gary Thank you for confirming my suspicions

Comment: Whoever keeps downvoting my questions, please stop. This has become too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u=e^t-1$$
$$t=\ln(u+1)$$
$$dt=\frac{du}{u+1}$$
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t-1}dt=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{s-1}(u+1)}{u(u+1)}du$$
Perhaps you might have made a mistake in your substitution. Also, as the comments mentioned, the domain for $s$ doesn't include the roots of the zeta function. For instance, using a substitution we find the following integral diverges for all real $s$
$$\int_0^\infty\ln^{s-1}(t+1)dt=\int_0^\infty u^{s-1}(e^u-1)du=\Gamma(s)-\infty$$